# AltBeacon Advertising Interval

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1(ble_uuid)
                .setId2(major_lite)
                .setId3(minor_lite)
                .setManufacturer(0x004c) //for iBeacon
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l}))
                .build();
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"); //iBeacon

        final BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(
                getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(context);

        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e("RunTest", "Failure: " + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.e("RunTest", "Success... " + settingsInEffect);
            }
        });

        Log.e("RunTest", "START...");


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (beaconTransmitter.isStarted()) {
                    Log.e("RunTest", "STOPPED...");
                    beaconTransmitter.stopAdvertising();
                    soloPassView.setBluetoothAdvertising(false);
                    soloPassView.BeaconStarted(false);
                }
            }
        }, 2000);
```

I have scene something strange that if i advertise an android device as beacon and call stop after 2 seconds in the Locate android app, I have tested that it will continuous to advertise for 10 to 11 secs ?

Can i decrease the interval of advertising in Altbeacon or any other method to advertise just for 5 seconds ?

Thanks in advance for the help.